# Fecth JSON URL in React Native

Tags: react-native, api

I am trying to obtain the data from this website: https://reactnative.dev/movies.json

I use the following code:

```
fetch("https://reactnative.dev/movies.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                dataSource: responseJson
            })
        }, 2000)

        Alert.alert(responseJson)

    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))


    return (
        <FlatList
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={this.onRefresh} tintColor={themes[theme].auxiliaryText} />
            }
        />

    
    );
};
```

My problem is that Alert.alert (responseJson) throws the following error:
[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxV9s.png)

... and I would like to get the data for the flatlist.

Who helps me, please?

**UPDATE:**

```
...

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            moviesList: '',
        };
    }

... 
renderScroll = () => {
        const { moviesList } = this.state;

    fetch("https://reactnative.dev/movies.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    moviesList: responseJson.movies
                })
                Alert.alert(moviesList)
            }, 2000)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

...
```

I would like Alert.alert to receive the data. That is to say, get the data out of the fetch function.

If inside the Alert.alert I put responseJson.movies if the data appears, but if I put moviesList it won't

---

If I post the following in the browser console it sends me an undefined error. I just want to receive the data from outside the function.

```
fetch("https://reactnative.dev/movies.json")
.then(response => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            moviesList: responseJson.movies
        })

    }, 2000)
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))

alert(this.moviesList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must print your response data by console.log and make sure what the response data is.
According to your error, I think you are getting Object type data after fetching, but you need to assign String into Alert.alert, therefore I suggest you try the following.

```
Alert.alert(responseJson.title)
```

Comment: responseJson.title works, but, it doesn't work when I put responseJson.movies.id, I get the error from the image above.

Comment: yes, you might get same issue when you put responseJson.movies.id because reponseJson.movies are Array Object, therefore you should try like this.
reponseJson.movies[0].id
or
you can select an index among the Array object using "map" function

Comment: Check out my post update, please.

Comment: setState doesn't return the value immediately, so you can try it like this.
this.setState( (loading: false,  moviesList: responseJson.movies) => {
   Alert.alert(moviesList[0]);
})
please don't put movesList into Alert.alert() since it's array object.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this code it seems to be working. Is that what you are looking for?

with currElement you have access to the filmed object.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
function Home() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [data, saveData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://reactnative.dev/movies.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson.movies)
        saveData(responseJson.movies)
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }, [])
  console.log(data)

  return isLoading ? (
    <p> i am loading</p>
  ) : (
    <ul>
      {data.map(currElement => (
        <li key={currElement.id}> {currElement.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: When I try this way I get a hook error. Look at the update that I made on my post. I want to get the data from moviesList, use it outside of the function.